# How can I slow down I/O operation in a disk when the LVM is being re-sized?

Tags: linux, lvm

I want to re-size a LVM volume online in my Linux box.

It is taking very long time to complete, since there are I/O operations being performed on that volume.

Is there any way I can tell every other process which are writing to that disk to wait
until the re-sizing is done ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [IOTOP](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) to know what processes are writing and then renice them I guess, or shut them down for a while.

Comment: Shutting down the service will be very expensive. I am already using nice to set the priority but still it is taking long time than normal. Is there any other way I can signal the kernel to put the rest of the I/O request in queue ?